# Skrollr: Smooth scrolling

Tags: scroll, parallax, smoothing, skrollr

I would like to achieve a smooth scrolling when turning a mouse wheel. Currently, when I do one turn, the scrollbar kinda jumps and the animation is jumpy.

Example of this behaviour:
http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Can this scrolling be achieved using skrollr only? If so, how?
I tried following code

```
var s = skrollr.init({
render: function(data) {

            //Debugging - Log the current scroll position.
            console.log(data.curTop);
        },

        smoothScrolling: true,
        smoothScrollingDuration: 500,
                    easing: {
            WTF: Math.random,
            inverted: function(p) {
                return 1-p;
            }
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't make a big difference. The animation is little bit smoother (i.e. background slides for a while and then stops), but the scrolling itself is still jumpy.

I would prefer to solve this with skrollr only as I think it is prepared for it instead of adding another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote from Petr Tichy ([ihatetomatoes.net](https://ihatetomatoes.net/)):

> For smooth animations, animate cheap properties.
>
> The best result you'll get, when you keep animating only the cheap CSS
>   properties.
>
> - transform: scale(1.2)
> - transform: translateX(100px)
> - transform: rotate(90deg)
> - opacity: 0.5
>
> These 4 properties will let you change the size, position, rotation
>   and opacity of your elements.
>
> Combination of these CSS properties will enable you to create pretty
>   much most of you ideas and will get you the best results.
>
> If you come across lagging and choppy scrolling animations, give the
>   animated element transform: translateZ(0).
>
> This will promote the element into composite layers and will get rid
>   of the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this script

```
jQuery(function () {

        var $window = jQuery(window);
        var scrollTime = 0.5;
        var scrollDistance = 150;


        $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 || -event.originalEvent.detail / 3;
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
            var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta * scrollDistance);

            TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
                scrollTo: {
                    y: finalScroll,
                    autoKill: true
                },
                ease: Power1.easeOut,
                overwrite: 5
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also *(With Chrome on Mac)*

**I solved by this plug-in :**
https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll

```
<!-- After jQuery -->
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$.srSmoothscroll();</script>
```

Comment: This is not applicable re: skrollr options.